# How do i calculate power without math.pow c#

Tags: c#

i'm new in C#
and i need help to fill the method below:

static double ToPower(double x, int n){

to raise a number x to an integer power n (that is, to calculate the value xn). Remember that x-n = 1/xn, and that x0 = 1.
i can use loop or recursion can someone help with this.

Comment: use a loop or recursion.

Comment: Show your effort...? Also can you format the question properly?

Comment: `a**b == Pow(a, b) == Exp(b * Log(a))`

Comment: How would you do it on paper without using a calculator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using loops you could do something like this:

```
public double Pow(double num, int pow)
{
    double result = 1;

    if (pow > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= pow; ++i)
        {
            result *= num;
        }
    }
    else if (pow < 0)
    {
        for (int i = -1; i >= pow; --i)
        {
            result /= num;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Using enumerables you could do something like this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

...

```
public double Pow(double num, int pow)
{
    var sequence = Enumerable.Repeat(num, pow);

    if (pow > 0)
    {
        return sequence.Aggregate(1, (accumulate, current) => accumulate * current);
    }
    else if (pow < 0)
    {
        return sequence.Aggregate(1, (accumulate, current) => accumulate / current);
    }
    else
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: How If Power Number is Decimal???